# Google Photo API Method: albums.patch "isWriteable": true not working

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

I am trying https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/albums/patch? to make my album **writeable** so I can add "**Enrichment**" later for an existing album.

When I create an album from the API explorer it is writable by default and I am able to add enrichment.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/toPju52DwhCNw2Xg7 ( working one)

But I can not recreate all my albums from this API explorer once again, there must be a way to add enrichment to existing album which failing due to permission error. And I suspect as I donot see the "writeable" set to true by default it is set to false.

```
curl --request PATCH \
  'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums/ALzS9-hH7b67lbSv2iiuQQrJ7vjvbcNmLPDFZd77mjoRmJY7ixHtY9V5jy4z9QAUDYggFX3d1LJD?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"isWriteable":true,"id":"ALzS9-hH7b67lbSv2iiuQQrJ7vjvbcNmLPDFZd77mjoRmJY7ixHtY9V5jy4z9QAUDYggFX3d1LJD"}' \
  --compressed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**isWriteable** field is described as [Output only].
So you can't change it.

https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/albums#Album